r - plot a 2d surface approximation from xyz data for thermocline graph
I'm trying to replicate a thermocline plot like in the Surfer Software with xyz data.
Here is my data, use xyz data in sheet 2 :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AWlHFfsC7hiW3UAxdVWigvur6RXq_ar6/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104487116968420945811&rtpof=true&sd=true
my result :
2d thermocline profile plot
in this case I used MBA Surf interpolation to get surface approximation value and then plot it with geom_raster. But the result is not satisfied me yet.
I've tried to interpolate the data with Kriging but its takes long time to process the data. then I tried IDW interpolation but the result still seem not similar to Surfer result.
here is my code :
library(sp)
library(readxl)
library(gstat)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)
library(MBA)

ctd <- read_excel("C://Users/ASUS/Downloads/Thermoclean/S16-clean.xlsx", sheet = 2)
palcolor <- c("#040404","#10253F","#244B7A","#699AC2","#9FCAE6")


# Handling data (ignore dT if Depth < -300 m)
ctd_dc <- filter(ctd, depth > 300) %>% 
  mutate(dT = 0)
ctd_dcl <- filter(ctd, depth <= 300) %>% 
  mutate(dT = round(dT, 2))
total <- rbind(ctd_dc,ctd_dcl)
ctd_cl <- total[order(total$depth, decreasing = FALSE), ]
nctd <- ctd_cl[ctd_cl$dT > 0.05, ]

nctd %>% as.data.frame %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = Day, y = depth)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = dT)) + scale_y_reverse()+
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(palcolor),limits = c(0.05,0.5)) +
  labs(y = "depth (m)", x = NULL, colour = "dT (°C)")

# The date must be converted to numeric values
nctd$Day <- decimal_date(nctd$Day)
coordinates(nctd) <- ~ Day + depth
class(nctd)

# make grid
kolom <- seq(1,400,1)
baris <- seq(as.Date("2021/1/15"), as.Date("2024/6/15"), "month")
dday <- decimal_date(baris)
prediction_grid <- expand.grid(dday,kolom)
plot(prediction_grid)

coordinates(prediction_grid) <- ~ Var1 + Var2

# interp data with idw
pwr = 2.75
interp<-idw(dT~1,locations=nctd, newdata=prediction_grid,idp=pwr)
ctd_k <- interp %>% as.data.frame ()

ggplot(data = ctd_k, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = var1.pred)) + scale_y_reverse()+
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(palcolor),limits = c(0.15,1), na.value="white") +
  labs(y = "depth (m)", x = NULL, colour = "dT (°C)")

ncd <- data.frame(Day = ctd_k$Var1, Depth = ctd_k$Var2, dT = ctd_k$var1.pred)

# MBA interp
ctd_mba <- mba.surf(ncd, no.X = 1000, no.Y = 1000,)
dimnames(ctd_mba$xyz.est$z) <- list(ctd_mba$xyz.est$x, ctd_mba$xyz.est$y)
ctd_mba <- melt(ctd_mba$xyz.est$z, varnames = c('Day', 'Depth'), value.name = 'dT') %>% 
  filter(Depth > 0) %>% 
  mutate(dT = round(dT, 2)) 

#plot data
gp <- ggplot(data = ctd_mba, aes(x = Day, y = Depth), extend = T, sp = T) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = dT)) + scale_y_reverse()+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(palcolor), limits = c(0.15,0.75), na.value="#B9DDF1") +
  #geom_contour(aes(z = dT), breaks = 0.25, colour = "black") +
  geom_contour(aes(z = dT), breaks = 0.2, colour = "black") +
  labs(y = "depth (m)", x = NULL, fill = "dT (°C)") +
  coord_cartesian(expand = 0)
gp

I need your insight how to handle my data, please give me some advices :)
What I expected is thermocline plot similar to Surfer result like this :
surfer 2d thermocline plot
